# sed command to append file after match string

Tags: bash, sed

How to add file content after match in string

I have one file name is **lokesh.sh**

```
#_AdditionalMail:
#_WeekName:
TARGETDIR=`date +'%A'`
LOCKFILE=/tmp/backup_profile_lokesh.tmp
LOGFILE=/var/www/modules/backup/log/lokesh.log
me=`basename "$0"`
volumename=`sudo awk '/mnt/{i++}i==2' /var/www/modules/backup/profiles/"$me"`
chkmount=`sudo mount | grep -w "$volumename"`
```

In this file I want to add another file content.

**backup.txt**

```
allscript=`ls *.sh | paste -d "," -s`
export IFS=","
for script in $allscript; do
done
```

I want add content of backup.txt file content after line **LOGFILE=/var/www/modules/backup/log/lokesh.log** in **lokesh.sh**

**Expected Output After adding file**

```
#_AdditionalMail:
#_WeekName:
TARGETDIR=`date +'%A'`
LOCKFILE=/tmp/backup_profile_lokesh.tmp
LOGFILE=/var/www/modules/backup/log/lokesh.log
allscript=`ls *.sh | paste -d "," -s`
export IFS=","
for script in $allscript; do
done
me=`basename "$0"`
volumename=`sudo awk '/mnt/{i++}i==2' /var/www/modules/backup/profiles/"$me"`
chkmount=`sudo mount | grep -w "$volumename"`
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the command `r` in `sed` to append text read from backup.txt.
And this would take place after the line with the string "LOGFILE"

```
sed '/LOGFILE/ r backup.txt' lokesh.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may complete your task.

```
awk '/LOGFILE=\/var\/www\/modules\/backup\/log\/lokesh.log/{print;system("cat backup.txt");next} 1' lokesh.sh
```

**Explanation:** Simply searching for string `LOGFILE=/var/www/modules/backup/log/lokesh.log` with escaping `/` in it(to remove it's special meaning), once this string is found in any line then printing the current line and using `awk`'s `system` utility in which we could call shell commands. Using `cat backup.txt` command there to print the `backup.txt` file, after that mentioning `next`, which will skip all further statements. At last mentioned 1 will be printing all the lines, so `awk` works on method of `condition then action`. Here I am making condition TRUE by mentioning `1` and no action is specified so by default print action will happen(print of current line). Mentioning lokesh.sh as Input_file after that.

Comment: how we can update the same file .it is just printing ..not updating lokesh,sh file

Comment: @KMPrak, please append ` > temp && mv temp Input_file` to my solution.